# Display checkbox in Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a checkbox to Woocommerce checkout with this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'my_custom_order_notes' );

function my_custom_order_notes( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['my_new_order_notes'] = array(
  'label'       => __('Lorem ipsum', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'    => false,
    'clear'       => false,
    'type'        => 'checkbox'
);
return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_field_value_to_order_notes', 15, 2  );

function my_custom_field_value_to_order_notes( $order_id, $data ) {
if ( ! is_object( $order_id ) ) {
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
}
$order->set_customer_note( isset( $data['my_new_order_notes'] ) ? $data['my_new_order_notes'] : '' );
wc_create_order_note( $order_id, $data['my_new_order_notes'], true, true );
$order->save();
}
```

This is working but in order emails it shows "Notes: 1" and I would like it to be "Lorem ipsum: yes" if the checkbox is checked. I need to use the customer notes for this because I am also using an accounting software that retrieves Woocommerce order notes but it will not retreive any other custom data, so using the order notes is the only way. How can I adapt my code to display "Lorem ipsum: yes" in all order emails if the checkbox was checked by the customer?

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to tweak the call to `set_customer_note`:

```
$order->set_customer_note(
    !empty($data['my_new_order_notes']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
);
```

Comment: this displays "Notes: yes" or "Notes:no" in the order emails, but I need it to display Lorem ispum: yes or Lorem ispum: no.  (Lorem ipsum is the checkbox label)